# git rebase as close to HEAD as possible?

Tags: git, rebase

I've got a private branch in git that I've not touched in a while. I'd like to rebase it on top of `master`, so I:

```
git checkout master
git pull

git checkout my-branch
git rebase master

First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: a bunch of stuff
Applying: more stuff
Applying: and so on
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/foo.c
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
```

Oh no, I can't rebase directly to `HEAD`!

```
git rebase --abort  # sigh
```

What I usually do at this point is to attempt to "ratchet" my branch as close to `HEAD` as possible, by using `git rebase SHA1`, `git rebase SHA2` (where *SHA1*, *SHA2*, etc. are on `master`), until I find the most-recent point at which it rebases successfully.

My usual technique for picking candidate rebase points is to try immediately after each merge to master.

Is there a good way to automate this process?

Comment: What benefit do you get from rebasing on SHA1/2? You will eventually have to rebase on master and you will get the same conflicts.

Comment: Just fix the conflict and `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: If there _are_ successful merges in the rebase, they get applied, and I have fewer commits (and potential conflicts) on the branch to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe Git has what you are looking for out-of-the-box.

But, you could use a script and a Git alias to create a sort of "fuzzy rebase" command. This will try to rebase against another ref, and if it fails will walk up it's descendant's tree until it finds a ref that can be cleanly rebased against.

Here is a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# get ref
my $ref=shift @ARGV;
if (!defined $ref) {
    warn "need ref to rebase against!\n";
    exit 1;
}

# attempt rebase
`git rebase $ref 2>&1`;

# detect if conflict occurred
# if so, abort the rebase
# and try again with the rebase target's parent
my @result = `git ls-files --unmerged`;
if (scalar @result > 0) {
    print "failed at $ref\n";
    `git rebase --abort 2>&1`;
    system("$0 $ref~");
} else {
    print "done at $ref\n";
}
```

Let's say you had this at `~/scripts/fuzzyRebase.pl`. Define a Git alias like this:

```
git config --global alias.fuzzyRebase !/~/scripts/fuzzyRebase.pl
```

Now, whenever you want to invoke your fuzzy rebase you can use:

```
git fuzzyRebase master
```

Comment: I'll give that a go, but actually thinking about it, that gets complicated in the face of merges-to-master, because there's nothing particularly special about "master" when walking backwards and hitting a merge. Hmmm...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe agreed...I think the main point here is that what you are seeking will require some scripting, and that scripting could get complicated with all sorts of edge cases like merge-commits

Comment: One note here, you don't have to `git ls-files --unmerged`, the exit status of `git rebase` is 0 on success, 1 (nonzero generally, but actually currently 1) on conflict.